# F# - Uppercase the first string in a list

Tags: f#, functional-programming

In my code showen below I am trying to change the first letter of the first string to uppercase and also set a question mark:

```
let strList = ["are"; "you"; "hungry"]

let rec add l = match l with
                |[] -> ["?"]
                |x::xs -> x::(add xs)

add strList
```

where I managed to fix the question mark at the end and get this list back:

```
["are"; "you"; "hungry"; "?"]
```

Are there any ideas on how to change the first letter in `are` to `Are` in the recursive function `add` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a new function which applies the correct transformation to the first element in the input list and calls into the recursive function you already have with the rest of elements:

```
open System

let strList = ["are"; "you"; "hungry"]

let add l =
  let rec add l =
    match l with
    | [] -> ["?"]
    | x::xs -> x::(add xs)

  let upper (s: string) =
    s |> Seq.mapi (fun i c -> match i with | 0 -> (Char.ToUpper(c)) | _ -> c)  |> String.Concat

  match l with 
  | [] -> add l
  | x :: xs -> (upper x) :: (add xs)

add strList
```

And the output is like you'd expect it:

```
val strList : string list = ["are"; "you"; "hungry"]
val add : l:string list -> string list
val it : string list = ["Are"; "you"; "hungry"; "?"]
```

Comment: There is a built-in method for capitalizing a word. let toTitleCase = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase

Comment: Note that ToTitleCase can change more than just the first letter [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase?view=netcore-3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase?view=netcore-3.1)